# Date bug in dygraph in dygraphs package (using JavaScript) in R

Tags: r, dygraphs

I plotted a dygraph using a `dygraph` function from a [dygraphs](http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/) package. My data were from dates 2014-12-10 till 2014-12-17

```
> str(seriesXts)
An ‘xts’ object on 2014-12-10/2014-12-17 containing:
  Data: num [1:8, 1:30] 0.928 0.977 0.935 0.989 0.854 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:30] "CiekawostkiFinanse" "CiekawostkiKobieta" "CiekawostkiMototech" "CiekawostkiSport" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
List of 1
 $ descr: chr "my new xts object"
```

but on a plot legend says they start 1 day ealier, check this figure:
On axis there is a date 12, but on legend there is a date 11...

[image: bug]

Any idea where is a bug?

To reproduce this bug try this code

```
library(archivist)
library(dplyr)
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("rstudio/dygraphs")
library(dygraphs)
seriesReactive <- loadFromGithubRepo( "db914a43536d4d3f00cf3df8bf236b4a", user= "MarcinKosinski", repo="Museum", value = TRUE)
dygraph(seriesReactive, main = "Dzienna proporcja kliknięć do odsłon dla danych struktur", ylab = "Proporcja") %>% 
    dyRangeSelector()
```

I've also posted this as an issue on rstudio's github https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/issues/22

Comment: This may be timezone related.

Comment: I don't know enough about R to help you, that's why I just commented instead of answering. Just check and see if it is timezone related. If it is, look for how to read Date values regardless of your local timezone.

Comment: Provide a reproducible example ...

Comment: I've added a code at the end that enables a reproducible example :)

Answer (score 1):

It's strange to be honest, it looks like the problem is not only with timezones but with scale also.

In theory dygraph uses the time zone of the client workstation, check [this](http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-timezones.html). But internally it keeps time in GMT (not sure about this, but it looks so), look:

`d <- dygraph(seriesReactive, main = "Dzienna proporcja kliknięć do odsłon dla danych struktur", ylab = "Proporcja") %>% 
    dyRangeSelector()
d$x$data[[1]]
[1] "2014-12-09T23:00:00Z" "2014-12-10T23:00:00Z" "2014-12-11T23:00:00Z" "2014-12-12T23:00:00Z"
[5] "2014-12-13T23:00:00Z" "2014-12-14T23:00:00Z" "2014-12-15T23:00:00Z" "2014-12-16T23:00:00Z"`

I am in CET time zone so I get 1 hour difference.

Now, because dyGraph uses my time zone, everything should be OK, but it isn't. However, if you change scale of dygraph by hand:

`d$x$scale <- "hourly"`

it starts to work as intended. So maybe some issues with extracting days?

According to [docs](http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-timezones.html) you could set option to use timezone from data

`indexTZ(seriesReactive) <- "CET"
dygraph(seriesReactive, main = "Dzienna proporcja kliknięć do odsłon dla danych struktur", ylab = "Proporcja") %>% 
  dyOptions(useDataTimezone = TRUE) %>%
  dyRangeSelector()`

but it doesn't work for me (nothing shows up). I don't know why but I don't have time to drill into this.

You could always make small workaround and set timezone to GMT in `xts` object.

`index(seriesReactive) <- as.POSIXct(format(index(seriesReactive), format="%Y-%m-%d"), tz = "GMT")
dygraph(seriesReactive, main = "Dzienna proporcja kliknięć do odsłon dla danych struktur", ylab = "Proporcja") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector()`

Comment: Thanks Bartek :) I'll look at this asap

Comment: tz = "GMT" isn't default parameter in ax.POSIXct?
I've tried this code on another computer, and there wasn't such a bug, there is an idea that maybe system timezone and DOS timezone are differnet somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Under the `dyOptions` add `labelsUTC = FALSE`. Alternatively, `useDataTimezone = TRUE`
Example `dyOptions(labelsUTC = FALSE)`